# Can I fetch a count of records with LIMIT n,m in one query?

Tags: mysql

In MySQL, I need to fetch the number of rows:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM Table
```

and also get some records in the middle:

```
SELECT * FROM Table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 100,5
```

Can I do both in one `SELECT` statement?

Comment: Which version of MySQL? It's possible prior to 8.0.17 but not later, unless you want to do a subquery (which is still technically another ``SELECT`` statement). https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/28218/how-to-count-number-of-rows-with-limit

Comment: @kmoser: `5.7.25` so I guess no. Thanks, I was just trying to optimize it a little bit.

Comment: 5 is prior to 8 (although I'm not sure what difference kmoser thinks this would make)

Comment: @Strawberry Prior to 8.0.17 you could use the ``SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`` modifier in conjunction with ``FOUND_ROWS()`` to determine the number of rows, but as of 8.0.17 [this feature has been deprecated](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows).

Answer (score 1):

You build an unique query using a cross join  on nested  subquery for count

```
  SELECT Table.* , t.my_count
  FROM Table 
  CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT count(*) my_count
    FROM Table
  ) t 
  ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 100,5
```

Comment: Thanks. Would it be more efficient than running two queries though?